# best database solution for multiple date time column indexing

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, amazon-dynamodb

I am creating a duty management system for workers, the database will contain the following columns

---

### ID | STAFF_ID | DUTY_ID | DUTY_START | DUTY_END

This system is required to know how many staffs are working in between the given time.

I am currently using mysqli which seem to be slow as the table data is increasing.

I am looking for a suitable service which can handle daily 500,000 records insert and search within DUTY_START and DUTY_END indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start-End ranges are nasty to optimize in large tables.

Perhaps the best solution for *this* situation is to do something really bad -- split off the date.  (Yeah 2 wrongs may make a right *this time*.)

```
ID | STAFF_ID | DUTY_ID | date | START_time | END_time
```

Some issues:

- If a shift spans midnight, make 2 rows.
- Have an index on `date`, or at least starting with `date`.  Then even though the query must scan all entries for the day in question, at least it is *much* less than scanning the entire table.  (All other 'obvious solutions' get no better than scanning *half* the table.)

If you want to discuss and debate this further, please provide `SELECT` statement(s) based on either your 'schema' or mine.  Don't worry about performance; we can discuss how to improve them.